# Issue with authenticate using SFDX CLI in Linux: Error (1): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setContentsFromObject')

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, authentication

I'm building an CI/CD pipeline with Gitlab and AWS EC2 instance (Linux x84_64). I successfully installed SFDX CLI and try to authenticate using SFDX commands but they returned the same errors:

```
Error (1): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setContentsFromObject')
```

[image]

[image]

I have searched many topics and assumed that this bug is not related to CLI version, it's more like related to Linux (because SFDX warning that it does not fully support Linux system)

[image]

Please help me on this!!!
Thanks in advance!!

Update: After hours of searching, I assume that related to Linux system and change my VM from Linux to Windows for hosting Gitlab Runners, and it works perfectly!! =)))

Comment: Have you tried other versions to install? Also how are you installing it?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Yeah i have try another version of CLI. And the reason i say it related to Linux system because i have tested in Windows (same command, authen token, auth url). It works in Windows but not Linux. Every authen sfdx command (excep through browser) has the same above error.